# How do I query Direct3D9 for the total amount of video memory?

Tags: directx, direct3d, directx-9, direct3d9

Sorry if this seems like an obvious question, but I'm just not finding anything online.

In Direct3D9, how do I get the total amount of video memory for a specific display device? I'm looking for a programmatic equivalent of running dxdiag and looking it up there. (I *don't* care about *available* memory; just how many MB the video card has.)

Knowing how much memory a user's video card has will be useful information in crash reports.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8.x, and Windows 10, use DXGI. The details are in the `DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC` structure: `DedicatedVideoMemory`, `DedicatedSystemMemory`, `SharedSystemMemory`.

> If you are targeting these operating systems, use should probably be using Direct3D 11 and not legacy Direct3D 9.

See the [Video Memory](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/blob/master/VideoMemory/Readme.docx?raw=true) sample from [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples).

Comment: Is it possible to co-mingle DXGI and DirectX9? Rewriting my thousands of lines of DX9 code in DX11 is out of the question, in my particular case.

Comment: Then stick with DirectX 9 but realize debugging on modern versions of the OS is more difficult and you will have to bite the bullet and rewrite it at some point.

Comment: And yes, you can use DXGI with Direct3D 9 on Windows Vista or later for enumeration and such, but you have you use the legacy APIs to actually create the Direct3D 9 device.